# allow a user to modify files via FTP

Tags: ftp

I have a single user allowed to connect via FTP (ProFTPD) but when I'm connected with this user I can't modify the files. How can I fix this ? I have a dedicated server running Debian 7

Thanks for your help

Comment: The user doesn't have permissions. See http://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/permissions.html

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf]. It's off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a permissions issue. For proftpd I would imagine that would be in a configuration file, a quick google search tells me that the configuration file is called proftpd.conf.

edit the umask values in nano or something to set the permissions you need.

```
chmod -777
```

heres a link to what a basic proftpd.conf file would look like so you know where to look to set the uMask. http://www.proftpd.org/docs/configs/basic.conf

Hope this helps.